# Printing file content on one line

Tags: bash

I'm completely lost trying to do something which I thought would be very straightforward : read a file line by line and output everything on one line.

I'm using bash on RHEL.
Consider a simple test case with a file (test.in) with following content:

```
one
two
three
four
```

I want to have a script which reads this files and outputs:

```
one two three four
Done
```

I tried this (test.sh):

```
cat test.in | while read in; do
    printf "%s " "$in"
done
echo "Done"
```

The result looks like:

```
# ./test.sh
 foure
Done
#
```

It seems that the printf causes the cursor to jump to the first position on the same line immediately after the %s.  The issues holds when doing `echo -e "$in \c"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your file contain special characters ?

Comment: No, no special chars at all.  I just had the good sense to try and run the same script + file on an HPUX box with KSH and there the script works as expected.  Must be a setting in my Linux/BASH combination.

Comment: There are at least 4 answers that work for your use case albeit with different efficiency. Did you try them? I see no accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

another answer:

```
tr '[:space:]' ' ' < file
echo
```

This must be safest and most efficient as well. Use `\n` if you want to only convert new lines instead of any white spaces.

Comment: downvoted for not ending the string in a newline as in OP's example. Also this is identical to my answer posted an hour before minus the deficiency.

Comment: @123, good catch (I fixed) ;) issue is that your answer though reads whole file to memory so try doing that with a huge file

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
echo -- $(<test.in); echo 'Done'

one two three four
Done
```

Comment: put `-n` in beginning of your file and see what happens;

Comment: Hm, must be I'm missing something in my environments, because, as with another approach listed above, this solution gives the same issue at my side.

Comment: @domi756: I am sure your file has DOS file endings. Run `dos2unix` before this command.

Comment: @anubhava: I am sure it does not because I created the test file from scratch using vi on the Linux host :)

Comment: Can you provide output of `cat -vte file` in your question

Answer (score 0):

`` echo -- `cat file` | tail -c +4 ``

the `--` is to protect you from command line options. But in my shell the `--` is printed out. I think that might be a bug. Will have to check.

So you need to check if you have to include `| tail -c +4` in your implementation.